# Adding the list of initstate to the cache

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In the below code I am trying to get that _songList added to the cache so that I can stream my audio smoothly without any delay or interruption. I tried with flutter_cache manager using final file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile() but it did not help me anymore.

```
  @override
  void initState()  {
    Provider.of<SongProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .getSongsByCollection('Worship')
        .then((value) {
      setState(()  {
        _songList = value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  Provider.of<SongProvider>(context, listen: false)
      .getSongsByCollection('Worship')
      .then((value) async {
    setState(() {
      _songList = value;
    });

    final cacheManager = DefaultCacheManager();
    final file = await cacheManager.getSingleFile(value[0].songUrl);
    // replace `value[0].songUrl` with the actual URL field in your `_songList` model

  });
  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: thanks.  final cacheManager = DefaultCacheManager();
      for (var i = 0 ; i <= _songList.length; i++ ) {
        final file = await cacheManager.getSingleFile(value[i].music);
        _urlList.add(file);

      }

     //    _cacheList.add(file);

    });
    I was able to add all the cached url to a list but I am little confused on getting other elements of the list like lyrics or image or others